# Where'd PHP for cygwin go? Still have a copy with PHP installed? Wanna share?

Tags: windows, php, cygwin

I used to have cygwin with PHP installed and working, but the hard drive on which was installed crashed catastrophically.  Cygwin was just about the only thing that hadn't propagated to my backup yet, so I lost it, and, unfortunately, PHP doesn't seem to be available for cygwin anymore :(

Something I realized, however, was that cygwin is completely self-contained and portable just by copying the cygwin folder.  Would anyone care to share a copy of their cygwin folder with PHP installed?

Or, perchance, maybe someone can point me in the right direction to get PHP installed on cygwin?  All the results I've found are out-of-date info and no longer working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe Cygwin proper ever included PHP, but [the Cygwin Ports project](http://sourceware.org/cygwinports/) (which "provides Cygwin binary and source packages for a large variety of programs and libraries") lets you install PHP via the regular Cygwin installer (basically by telling the installer to use a Cygwin Ports mirror, instead of a regular Cygwin mirror, as the download site). Instructions for this are at http://sourceware.org/cygwinports/.

Comment: I just tested it with the latest Cygwin installer, and PHP is definitely not in the repositories.

Comment: @JeroenBaert: I don't know what you mean. If you mean that PHP is not in the default Cygwin repositories, then -- sure, that's a given. (The OP said it, I said it, there's no need to comment and say it.) If you mean that it's not in the repositories of the Cygwin Ports project, then you're simply mistaken: it's in the PHP category, with the name "php: PHP Hypertext Processor". I tried it myself. You must have done something wrong when following the instructions.

Comment: @ruakh: I looked around for a repository with PHP, but all of the ones that I found were dead.  Did you find one working?  Could you point me to it?

Comment: @user1940006: My answer links (twice!) to such a repository. Did the instructions not work for you?

Comment: Ugh ... sorry, it's late my reading comprehension goes down teh tubez :|

Comment: OK, looking at this with fresh eyes now ... I've tried those mirrors, none of them work, as I explained.  They all fail.

Comment: @user1940006: Glad to hear it! What did you have to do?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why... I'm sitting here on my Windows 7 box with Apache, MySQL and PHP installed the good old fashioned way, looking at my Cygwin curious as to what exactly you are seeking. Given that, I would recommend a Vagrant VM anyways.

Comment: @ruakh: I should have written it down, but it was one of the ports from the link that you posted.  I'm sure I'd been there before, I guess I just found one that was working this time.  Thanks.

Comment: @Michael Wales: I do actually have a number of VMs installed, one of which is a LAMP setup as a testing environment for web development.  I prefer to use PHP in Cygwin to run scripts against local files and do various processing tasks.  It just saves me the steps of futzing around with SAMBA and so on.  Plus it gives me a bunch of useful Linux utilities that I can use directly within the Windows filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Another valid option is using XAMPP, for an Apache / PHP / MySQL stack that runs on windows. Just extract & run, I always use this for a quick test deployment:

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html

Comment: I suppose that would work, but I also would like to have other Linux utilities at my disposal.

Comment: if you installed xampp/wamp you can put the path to the php.exe into your environment variables and cygwin will be able to access it as well